# Ember binding to array element

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to set up an ember binding between a controller and a model.  The controller is part of an array (see question [Ember.js views (unlimited number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740417/ember-js-views-unlimited-number)), and so I'm trying to set up the binding to an element in a the model (an ArrayProxy) with the same index as the index of the controller itself.

The binding works if I link it to a non-indexed element of the ArrayProxy, but not if I try set an element of the array.  So, if I set up the binding like:

```
answerBinding: 'App.SurveyData.test'
```

and in App.SurveyData set 'test' to be a string, say "StackOverlow", the two way binding is set up correctly.  If I set up a binding like

```
answerBinding: 'App.SurveyData.content'
```

where content is an array, I can view in the console that 'answer' has a value of 'Array[2]' and each element equals 'Test object' as expected

When I try to set up the answerBinding as

```
answerBinding: 'App.SurveyData.content[0]'
```

which is trying to link answer to the first element in SurveyData as required, I can view in the console that 'answer' has a value of undefined.

Code is at http://jsfiddle.net/reubenposthuma/dyLGG/1/

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember's bindings only work for properties. Specific indexes of Array cannot be bound, unless you do so via a computed property, like:

```
answerBinding: 'App.SurveyData.firstItem'
```

...and in App.SurveyData defined the computed property:

```
firstItem: function() { return this.objectAt(0); }.property('content')
```

Think about it this way: the array index is an argument to the `[]` function (not literally, but for the sake of this explanation.) Bindings cannot except arguments; they are purely a static path to a property to bind.

Comment: Remember that Ember arrays already come with ``firstObject`` and ``lastObject``.

Answer (score 0):

As Mars said, bindings cannot accept indices of arrays, so I created a workaround.  It is one way, although it could be modified to have an observer on the array itself for two way bindings.  For my purposes (taking data from a survey and putting it in a answer array) one way bindings work perfectly.

```
answerObserver: function() {
  App.SurveyData.content[this.id-1] = this.answer;
}.observes('answer'),
```

whenever the data (in this case a textbox) changes, the changes will be copied into the index of the array.